# How to test that specific assets (JS, CSS) are available in layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, asset-pipeline

Is it possible -- or even sane -- to verify that specific parts of the asset pipeline are available in specific layouts of a Rails app?

I'm setting up a new Rails 4.2 app with Twitter Bootstrap 4 (incl. its dependencies such as Tether), FontAwesome and DataTables. The scaffold is working fine so far.

As the whole thing is kind of training on web development, self-control (w.r.t. software development, i.e. actually stick to a balanced mix of TDD and BDD), I want to make sure to test almost everything that could possibly go wrong. That includes the availability of all the framework stuff mentioned above on all end points where it's required.

Ultimately, I want to write something like the following:

```ruby
describe 'layouts/application.html.erb', type: :layout, js: true do
  it 'has jQuery' do
    render
    expect(render).to have_js :jquery
  end

  it 'has TWBS v4' do
    render
    expect(render).to have_js :twbs4
    expect(render).to have_css :twbs4
  end
end
```

Obviously, these `.to have_js :jquery` and `.to have_{js,css} :twbs4` need to have something in the background such as a Javascript evaluation of `$.fn.jquery`.

Is it even sane to test such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it sane, possible, even helpful, to test your assets? Certainly! Different types of asset error affect your app in different ways and in different environments, so I recommend testing them in different ways:

- It's best to catch asset problems in testing to the extent that you can, rather than waiting until your app hits your pre-production or production environment. Most of your Javascript and a lot of your CSS is needed for your app to function correctly. So, if you haven't already, write a few acceptance tests (RSpec feature specs, Cucumber scenarios, or something similar) to test that your important pages load and function correctly. They will both test your functionality and incidentally test that your assets that affect functionality are loading. Testing any Javascript-based behavior will do to check Javascript assets. Testing a behavioral feature that relies on CSS, such as an element that is hidden and revealed, is the way to check CSS assets. Write the fewest acceptance tests you need to test your important scenarios so your test suite doesn't take forever.

  Note that while it's efficient to let your acceptance specs test your assets via app functionality, it's also the only straightforward way to do it at all. Testing asset loading means testing a running server, which means acceptance tests. Rails acceptance tests generally use Capybara, which lets you click on web pages like a user would but does not give you a way to directly make an HTTP request for something other than an HTML page. You could do that by importing [`Rack::Test`](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test) methods into your acceptance tests, but given that

  - normal acceptance tests test most of your assets already, and
  - you'll need to do some testing in your production or pre-production environment anyway (see below)

  it's probably not worth the trouble.
- In my experience there are classes of Javascript and CSS asset errors which only appear in one's pre-production or production environment, and errors with images and other assets like fonts usually *only* show up in those environments. So it's valuable to run some smoke tests on your pre-production environment. I've found it works pretty well to just fetch some URLs (your home page, examples of other important page types, important assets) with curl or however you like, ensure they respond with HTTP status 200, and ensure that the textual responses contain some expected string. Since many production-only asset errors actually break all pages that load those assets (e.g. errors in `config/environments/production.rb`), smoke-testing only a few pages is sufficient to catch the majority of production-only asset errors.

The above strategies only find asset errors that affect many assets or pages in your app. If you wanted to test every single asset, you'd need to do a bit more work to make a list in a maintainable way and test every element of the list. I don't think it would be worth it. You need to monitor your app's 400 and 500 errors anyway; that will catch the less-common errors that the above strategies don't.